# CSV File doesn't look like a table

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, csv

I have downloaded a csv file, and when I open it in excel, it looks like the image below.

I would like to view the data in a table format. with each field in a separate column.

[image]

Comment: How are you opening it? What are you doing to tell Excel that it is a CSV file?  Have you tried renaming it to a name that ends with ```.csv```?

Comment: When I downloaded it, I click on "save as csv". It's name ends with ".csv". It's automatically is opened with excel. But it doesn't build a table with the separated values. It's only on my computer, on other computers things work as they have to.

Comment: @TallyRachelin, use Text to Column and pick Comma as delimiter.

Comment: What are your computer's settings w.r.t. locale? That is, default decimal/comma delimiters? Seems that Excel wants you to use `;` as a CSV delimiter.

Comment: From screenshot , it looks like you have not mentioned the file type as ".csv" in your filename , can you confirm that your filename ends with the correct file extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Select Column A
- On the data tab, click `Text to columns`
- Ensure `Delimited` is selected and click next
- Ensure `comma` is selected and click finish.

See images below for reference.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Aaaaah CSV files and their oh so many flavours...

PeterH's answer would do the job quickly, but would not really well handle stuff like line feeds within a field (from what you screenshot show, you seemm to be in this case), or differences in character encoding.

Excel is very bat at opening CSV files if you  double-click them from the file explorer, but there's a hidden gem in recent versions of Excel (you seem to have Office 365), that is very robust robust: go to `Data` > `From a text/CSV file` and then pick the encoding (start with `65001: Unicode (UTF8)` and check in the sample below if the special characters appear nicely), the separator (comma is obviously the one in your case), and then click on `Load`, select where you want the import to be, and you should be done.

An alternative is to install LibreOffice that does a very good job at opening CSV files.